# pg-promise ColumnSet with nested object prop?

Tags: pg-promise

What is the proper syntax for a object child as a column prop?

```
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
  {
    name: 'uid',
    prop: 'id'
  }, {
    name: 'created_at'
    prop: 'member.created_at // <-- error
  }
])
```

Cant seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the regular [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) query formatting (using [Named Parameters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters)) supports nested properties, specifically [helpers](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html) do not, due to certain templates-related complexity.

However, it is not necessary, because [ColumnSet](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) syntax for columns is very flexible (see type [Column](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html)), and supports dynamic property resolution.

Simply update the column to use `init`, to get the value dynamically:

```js
{
    name: 'created_at',
    init: c => c.source.member.created_at
}
```

For the field, we go to the `source` object, as [per documentation](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.initCB), and take what we need.

**Alternative syntax:**

```js
{
    name: 'created_at',
    init(c) {
        // with this syntax, this = c.source

        return this.member.created_at;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Vitaly! Thanks so much for the help. Great library :)